# How to Use CMake for Non-Interactive Build on Windows?

Tags: windows, build, cmake

I want to set up automated build using CMake on Windows. I am using Visual Studio 2005.

**Update**: Here is what I am using:

I set devenv.exe to my PATH. Then to build I run the command below. I am using Hudson to build.

devenv Crackpot.sln /build Debug /project ALL_BUILD

As per http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronhallberg/archive/2007/06/29/building-from-the-command-line-with-devenv.aspx prefer to use "devenv" and not "denenv.exe" as the latter may spawn a GUI thus hanging the build.

Comment: can you make the question more specific? It is not clear to me what you would like to see from the community.

Comment: @Adriaan I meant what to run, after I run "cmake -G" to generate visual studio project files. Sorry, evidently it was not clear to you.

Comment: For posterity: the usual way to do this is to use the "NMake Makefiles" generator and run `nmake`.  This uses Microsoft's own `nmake`, which is a Windows version of `make`.

Comment: Use msbuild instead of devenv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question. You use it exactly like for any other build system. Just specify "Visual Studio 8 2005" (little bit weird, but you can get a list of all supported systems by calling cmake without parameters) and you'll get a solution that can be built on the command line either with `devenv.exe /build` or with MSBuild.

The only thing that is a little bit complicated is if you want to generate the solution when Visual Studio is not installed, like on a build server. You can, of course, just install it, but I prefer not to install things you don't need. In that case, you have to fake it to accept MSBuild as the build command line (by specifying a batch file as build tool at the command line, that just reorders the arguments so MSBuild accepts them), so that it won't start bitching about how it misses Visual Studio (which is so crazy, since the CMake people are from the command-line world...)

Oh, and if what you really want is just to build an existing Visual Studio solution on the command line, you don't need CMake. Just call MSBuild or `devenv /build`.

Comment: Yes i was looking for the step after running cmake. Thanks, that was so helpful.

Answer (score 34):

The simplest way I found to doing this was:

`% cmake --build "buildDir"`

you can also add `--target`  and `--config 'Debug|Release|...'`

Comment: That's actually the most helpful answer in this thread and the only one that really answers the question. This allows anyone running cmake in a non-visual studio shell to build everything, including for example, the "install" target.

Answer (score 9):

You can run CMake from the command line.
You could run.

```
cmake.exe -G"Visual Studio 8 2005" -H<source_dir> -B<build_dir>
```

Below is a snippet from the original command line usage output.
Notice that the -H and -B option are not documented there. But they can be used to explicitly define the source and build directories on the command line.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.6\bin>cmake
  cmake version 2.6-patch 4
  Usage

  cmake [options] <path-to-source>
  cmake [options] <path-to-existing-build>

  Options
  -C <initial-cache>          = Pre-load a script to populate the cache.
  -D <var>:<type>=<value>     = Create a cmake cache entry.
  -U <globbing_expr>          = Remove matching entries from CMake cache.
  -G <generator-name>         = Specify a makefile generator.
  -Wno-dev                    = Suppress developer warnings.
  -Wdev                       = Enable developer warnings.
  -E                          = CMake command mode.
  -i                          = Run in wizard mode.
  -L[A][H]                    = List non-advanced cached variables.
  -N                          = View mode only.
  -P <file>                   = Process script mode.
```

Here are the available generators.

```
Generators

The following generators are available on this platform:
  Borland Makefiles           = Generates Borland makefiles.
  MSYS Makefiles              = Generates MSYS makefiles.
  MinGW Makefiles             = Generates a make file for use with
                                mingw32-make.
  NMake Makefiles             = Generates NMake makefiles.
  Unix Makefiles              = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Visual Studio 6             = Generates Visual Studio 6 project files.
  Visual Studio 7             = Generates Visual Studio .NET 2002 project
                                files.
  Visual Studio 7 .NET 2003   = Generates Visual Studio .NET 2003 project
                                files.
  Visual Studio 8 2005        = Generates Visual Studio .NET 2005 project
                                files.
  Visual Studio 8 2005 Win64  = Generates Visual Studio .NET 2005 Win64
                                project files.
  Visual Studio 9 2008        = Generates Visual Studio 9 2008 project files.
  Visual Studio 9 2008 Win64  = Generates Visual Studio 9 2008 Win64 project
                                files.
  Watcom WMake                = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles= Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles
                              = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles
                              = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles
                              = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
```

Comment: Nice, though I'd expect that just telling him to run cmake on the command line to see the help would have been enough, since you already specified a valid sample commmand line :)

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for the obvious solution. Now we just need to find out if that was what Amit Kumar wanted :D

Comment: Sorry to have not made it clear, but I meant what to do after running cmake. The answer by OregonGhost works for me. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the bat file I created. It automatically creates the solution in the build folder you specify, each time deleting and creating a new build folder.

```
RMDIR C:\Users\abc /s /q

if EXIST C:\Users\abc GOTO FALIURE

MKDIR C:\Users\abc\build
CD C:\Users\abc\build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12" "C:\Users\abc\src"
EXIT

:FALIURE
CLS
echo "Failed to delete BUILD directory, Close all related files and programs and try again."
pause
EXIT
```