# How to build the msi from vdproj in cmake?

Tags: command-line, cmake, windows-installer, vdproj

I have testaddin.vdproj .I am trying to generate the .msi from that in cmake.But i don't know what command to execute in cmake add_custom_command.Please provide any solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use CMake for Non-Interactive Build on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459482/how-to-use-cmake-for-non-interactive-build-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used cmake but I can tell you the only way to build .vdproj projects is by calling `devenv.com /rebuild` with the correct parameters for your solution / platform / configuration settings.  Visual Studio deployment projects aren't MSBuild based so there is no other way to do it. Perhaps CMake has a higher level abstraction for this but under the covers this is what it must do.